# Почему директива ng-mouseenter не срабатывает на созданные директивой ng-if элементы SVG определенные в defs?

Tags: angularjs, svg

Совместно с AngularJS используется SVG.
В SVG нарисовано некоторое количество кругов.

```
<defs>
 <g id="test"> 
   <circle cx="0" cy="20" r="20"/>
 </g>
</defs>

<g ng-repeat="node in nodes" ng-mouseenter="focusIn()" ng-mouseleave="focusOut()">
  <g ng-if="visible">
     <ellipse id="2" cx="20" cy="0" rx="20" ry="20" />
     <g >
        <use id="3" xlink:href="#test" x="0" y="0" /> 
     <g/>
  <g/>
<circle id="1" cx="0" cy="0" r="20"/>
</g>



******************
$scope.visible = false;
$scope.focusIn=function() {
  $scope.visible = true;
}
$scope.focusOut=function() {
  $scope.visible = false;
}
```

Мы видим круги (`id=1`). Если мы наводим на один из них, то рядом с этим кругом появляется эллипс (`id=2`) и второй круг(`id=3`). При попытке навести курсор на элипс(`id=2`), ничего не происходит, т.е. он воспринимается как единое целое с кругом (`id=1`). Но если мы наведем на круг (`id=3`), то эллипс и этот круг пропадают, потому что срабатывает директива `ng-mouseleave`.

Как сделать так, чтоб `ng-mouseenter` реагировала и на круг (`id=3`)?

Comment: А может фиддл сделаешь?

Comment: не используйте `use`